# Simple validate condition based on 3 values

Tags: swift, validation

My user is required to give me 3 values: day, hour, and minute and the maximum value for each of them are below

```
let dayMaxValue = 7
let hourMaxValue = 23
let minuteMaxValue = 59
```

and there should at least 5 in minute if day and hour are both 0. For example, user can send me

```
input(day: 1, hour: 1, minute: 0)
// Or
input(day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 5)
// But not
input(day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 3)
```

Now I want to validate user input and see if they are valid

```
func checkUserInput(day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int) -> String {
    var result = [String]()

        if day > 0 {
            result.append("day")
        }

        if hour > 0 {
            result.append("hr")
        }

        if minute >= 5 {
            result.append("min")
        }

        if result.isEmpty {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

then I check if checkUserInput(day: x, hour: x, minute: x).isEmpty. If it does, user input is not valid else valid. Do you have a simple solution than mine in this case cause I think mine is not a good way? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a `String` to check if it's valid or not or do you simply need to return a `Bool`? And is that last block of code the implementation of your `input` method? Show the whole method.

Comment: It doesnt have to return String. I just find it is easy for me. Also, I already edited my post. Thanks

Comment: @NancyP Yeah, I was going to comment the same thing. This isn't what `String` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution which returns a Bool and checks the ranges of the date components

```
let dayMaxValue = 7
let hourMaxValue = 23
let minuteMaxValue = 59

func checkUserInput(day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Bool {
    return 0...dayMaxValue ~= day
        && 0...hourMaxValue ~= hour
        && ((hour + day == 0) ? 5 : 0)...minuteMaxValue ~= minute
}

checkUserInput(day: 1, hour: 1, minute: 0) // true
checkUserInput(day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 5) // true
checkUserInput(day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 3) // false
```

Comment: You could write the minute check as `((hour + day == 0) ? 5 : 0)...minuteMaxValue ~= minute`

Comment: @rmaddy Wow. I thought about it but couldn't imagine that it's valid syntax. 

Answer (score 0):

There's no real shortcut. Check each condition. Since you don't need a string, just use a `Bool` to indicate success or failure.

```
func checkUserInput(day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Bool {
    // First make sure all are in range
    guard day >= 0 && day <= dayMaxValue &&
          hour >= 0 && hour <= hourMaxValue &&
          minute >= 0 && minute <= minuteMaxValue
          else { return false }

    // Now check minute if hour and day are 0
    if day == 0 && hour == 0 && minute < 5 {
        return false
    }

    // If we get this far then it's valid
    return true
}
```

There are many ways to write the above code. Readability and debugability are better than cramming it all into one "fancy" line.